# Python plot_data

Tags: python, plot

can anyone teach me how to plot a csv

Comment: you are kind of going about it a strange way.  like, there's two different questions here. one is "how do i save this data to csv?" and the other is "how do i plot from csv?"  the two are not related to what is probably your real question "how do i plot this data?"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also to display plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('data_file.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    
    for row in plots:
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[1])

plt.bar(x, y, color = 'g', width = 0.72, label = "recall")
plt.xlabel('precision')
plt.ylabel('recall')
plt.title('Title')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

or

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with open('data_file.csv','r') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in lines:
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[1])

plt.plot(x, y, color = 'g', linestyle = 'dashed',
        marker = 'o',label = "precision")

plt.xticks(rotation = 25)
plt.xlabel('precision')
plt.ylabel('recall')
plt.title('Title', fontsize = 20)
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

So the thing is you have to call plt.plot() before with the data, and then call plt.show()
You could do something like:

```py
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = open("data_file.csv", "w")
w = csv.writer(f)
_ = w.writerow(["precision", "recall"])
rows = [[0.013,0.951],[0.376,0.851],[0.441,0.839],[0.570,0.758],[0.635,0.674],[0.721,0.604],[0.837,0.531],[0.860,0.453],[0.962,0.348],[0.982,0.273],[1.0,0.0]]
precision = [row[0] for row in rows]
recall = [row[1] for row in rows]
w.writerows(rows)
f.close()
plt.plot(precision, recall)
plt.show()
```

Above you have your data in `rows`, and your two variables divided in `precision` and `recall`. So now you can call `plt.plot(precision, recall)` and then `plt.show`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your code should have thrown a `NameError` at the last line, saying 'matplotlib' is not defined. Since you have already imported `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt`, use `plt` as a reference later in the code, instead of calling `matplotlib.pyplot` again and again.

You cannot pass a CSV file directly into the `plt.show()` function as an argument.

I suggest you use **Pandas** package to create a dataframe out of your CSV file and plot the values like in the below code:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

f = open("data_file.csv", "w")
w = csv.writer(f)
_ = w.writerow(["precision", "recall"])
w.writerows([[0.013,0.951],
             [0.376,0.851],
             [0.441,0.839],
             [0.570,0.758],
             [0.635,0.674],
             [0.721,0.604],
             [0.837,0.531],
             [0.860,0.453],
             [0.962,0.348],
             [0.982,0.273],
             [1.0,0.0]])
f.close()

Dataframe = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv')

plt.plot(Dataframe.precision, Dataframe.recall)
plt.show()
```

You can check more about **Pandas** documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and **matplot** documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/index.html)